# Carto Builder Azure Marketplace - default Postgres configuration causing poor performance

Tags: carto, performance, azure

We recently learned some valuable lessons which I wanted to share with the community.

We recently moved our map application from being hosted by CartoDB onto an [Azure Marketplace Carto Builder](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/carto.cartobuilder2?tab=Overview) VM.  There were several other changes we made to our application at the same time.

The application performance was much worse immediately after the move, especially under load, and in the browser's dev tools we saw lots of `HTTP 500` responses.

As well as trying to fix this or that potential performance factor with our application, we eventually also wondered:

> was the VM's Postgres configuration causing poor performance?

Answer (score 1):

We called CartoDB's support team, and established that `postgresql.conf` was the relevant config file for the PostGIS instance. Here is how it looked (minus lots of comment):

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 128MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

The Carto people recommended we apply the config values suggested by http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ with the parameters `DB Version: 9.5` and `DB Type: Mixed type of applications`, plus all the details of our machine's hardware configuration.  The resulting config turned out to be quite different from the one that came with the build.

```
max_connections = 1500
shared_buffers = 10GB
effective_cache_size = 30GB
work_mem = 3495kB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
max_worker_processes = 16
```

With this configuration we noticed the performance improved significantly, and the `HTTP 500` errors stopped.

In conclusion, the PostGIS config which came with the machine was indeed a significant factor in our performance issues.